# Selenium click Function Key

Tags: selenium

I am still new to Selenium test world, and I am currently using Selenium ChromeDriver for testing.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish, with no success:

1 - I have ~50 opened tabs in Chrome and I want to press F9 on on them all at one time

2 - After pressing F9 to all tabs, if certain text appears on the page (No results), then close the tab.

I hope someone can help at either of these two features.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? I don't think there is way to send key presses to every open tab at once -- you can write hacky workarounds to send key press to an individual tab, but that's about it. What are you trying to accomplish here? There is probably an easier way to meet your end goal. Given you are new to StackOverflow -- it's best to include a code sample of what you have tried so far, to demonstrate some level of effort on your end to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks Christine for your reply,

well unfortunately i didn't get yet a good form or sample for a code at the moment that's why i'm asking here for any help, tip or a hint.

my goal is that i have a multiple tabs urls 50 for ex. i have to run QA on all of them with shortcut key F9 and if this text appeared (No results) then i don't need it to be opened anymore.

so i need any possible help at either of these two features.

i don't know if this is the right way to get help :D

Comment: Opening 50 tabs seems like a really bad idea and would probably lead to a browser crash.  Is there a reason you have to do that?

Comment: Hi pcalkins ,

yes of course and it seems no problem with me to open even 70 tabs at my PC as i have 32 MB RAM with Core i 9 processor and already tested it and it works well

Comment: This sounds more like a load testing exercise rather than what Selenium was designed for. Perhaps a tool such as Jmeter (which does allow some custom integration with Selenium) will be more suitable. It allows for concurrent execution of a large number of threads, has many built-in tools already and allows for custom scripting.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way (that I am aware of) to send a key press to multiple window handles at once (each tab is called a window handle in Selenium), but you can loop through the windows and try to use some `Actions` class to send F9 key press to each page, then check for your desired text.

You will need to utilize `Driver.WindowHandles` to get a list of current open tabs, and `Driver.SwitchTo().Window()` to change the focus between tabs. `Actions` class can simulate sending the F9 key to the current window. `Driver.Close()` will close an existing tab.

Lastly, `WebDriverWait` will be used to wait for 'No Results' text to populate before the code evaluates whether or not the current tab should be closed. `WebDriverWait` will throw a `TimeoutException` if the desired element does not appear on the page within the specified time parameter, so we wrap `WebDriverWait` in a `try` / `catch` block to handle scenarios where 'No Results' both exists, and does not exist.

The following code sample in C# should get you started:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;


// given you have 50 tabs open already

// get window handles -- this is a List<string> with length 50, one for each tab
var handles = Driver.WindowHandles;

// iterate window handles, switch to the window, and send F9 key
foreach (var window in handles)
{
    // switch to the window
    Driver.SwitchTo().Window(window);

    // send F9 key press to the current tab
    new Actions(Driver).SendKeys(Keys.F9).Perform();

    // wait for 'No Results' text
    try 
    {
        new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'No Results')]")));

        // if TimeoutException is not thrown, then No Results text exists. so close the tab
        Driver.Close();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        // case: 'No Results' text does not exist. do not close the tab.
    }
}
```

This is a very general outline, and will almost certainly require some modification on your end to get it working completely. For example, the XPath used in `new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(), 'No Results')]")));` may need to be tweaked to ensure the correct element displaying 'No Results' text is located. Hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: Feel free to leave some feedback if you are downvoting -- I would be interested to see other approaches to this problem.

Comment: don't know why this was down-voted as it seems to answer the question very well.   (though you can avoid catching the exception if you use "visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy" and return a list of WebElements.  If the list size is 0 then it's not found...)

Comment: Great point about `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy`. I usually prefer coding styles that do not require exception handling -- sometimes it is helpful for new Selenium users to understand that `WebDriverWait` throws an exception. Perhaps the downvote is meant to discourage answers on poorly written questions, though community standard is to downvote the question, not the answers.